# how to set up app.yaml to redirect all urls with a . in them to files in a rails app's public folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine

I have a rails app on GCP using the App Engine Ruby Standard Environment (though this question could apply to any GCP app). At first I was trying to set things up so that `/*` gets handled by static files in the `public` directory of my Rails app, and otherwise falls back to the Rails app for unmatched URLs. This does not seem to be possible, however it occurred to me that I could set all urls containing a `.` to be handled by static files within `public` (in my particular app this would work fine).

I am confused on the documentation for `static_files` and `upload` (particularly the part about `/\1` in the example at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/ruby/config/appref#handlers_element, but here is the `handlers` section of my `app.yaml` file that I came up with. It does not work and simply 404s on all paths I throw at it:

```
handlers:
  - url: /*\.*
    static_files: public/\1
    upload: public/*
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    script: auto
```

This doesn't work as all paths go to the rails app which then 404s on all static file paths.

This one has the opposite problem -- static files work but no paths go to the rails app:

```
handlers:
  - url: /*\.*
    static_dir: public
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    script: auto
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked -- a slight tweak from one of the options from @gaefan

```
handlers:
  - url: /(.*\..*)
    static_files: public/\1
    upload: public/.*\..*
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    script: auto
```

Answer (score -1):

For your first example, I believe parentheses are required and you need to fix your regex. It should be something like:

```
handlers:
  - url: /(.*\..*)
    static_files: public/\1
    upload: public/*
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    script: auto
```

For the second one, you have a mistake in your regex.  It should be:

```
handlers:
  - url: /.*\..*
    static_dir: public
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    script: auto
```

Comment: Unfortunately with the first one I get `The requested URL /img/404-image.png was not found on this server.` for static files (I am also getting rails 404 errors for rails paths, but I think that is a separate issue -- at least they are going to the rails app).

Comment: *note: this is just me trying a random static url -- `/img/404-image.png` corresponds to `/public/img/404-image.png` and is itself 404ing via app engine's 404 mechanism.

Comment: Using the second method, everything goes to the rails app causing static files to 404.